# Not able to Cmd+ Click code coming through dependencies in STS 4

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

Facing a strange problem.

I recently moved my workspace to Java11. Earlier was using Spring Tool Suite 3.x but it was not working well with Java 11 so upgraded to 4.1.2 RELEASE.

The issue is I cant navigate (Cmd + Click) through dependencies code.

As shown in image below, I cant navigate through Objects below. However in my application code everything seems to be working. Also in earlier STS versions, didnt face any issues like this.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Objects"? If they're types, are those on the Java Build Path?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this bug:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/205

It is already fixed in the latest nightly builds of STS4 as well as the latest snapshot builds of LSP4E. If you don't want to wait for the STS 4.2.0 release (should be coming next week), you can install the latest version of LSP4E from their snapshot site.